# Regex returns a boolean not a string

Tags: java, regex

So I am trying to get the data from a line that looks like this:

```
GET /something HTTP/1.1
```

Now, I here is my code with the regex:

```
 final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8081);
    System.out.println("Listening on port 8081...");
    while (true) {
        final Socket clientSocket = server.accept();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line = reader.readLine();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GET \\/(.*?) HTTP");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);

        System.out.println(m.find());
```

the "/something" is what I need to get, and it will always be something different in actual usage. The code always prints out "true", instead of what should be in the string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: find returns a boolean and hence you get it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go 1 step further by using the `group` API to get the captured set values from your regular expression.

**Note:** `group` does not starts from position 0. The first element is just your **original** input value. You need to start from position 1.

Example:

```
private void doIt3() {
    String line = "GET /something HTTP/1.1 ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GET \\/(.*?) HTTP");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value => " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Found value => something

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the Group method to get the mathing value.

find only tells you if the string mathches:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("GET \\/(.*?) HTTP");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

`find` method in `Matcher` class is expected to return a `boolean` value not matched string.

You can see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) as follows:

> public boolean find(): Attempts to find the next subsequence of the
>   input sequence that matches the pattern.

You can use following code snippet to find all matching patterns.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("GET \\/(.*?) HTTP").matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```